# Looping through a database's schemas using Dynamic SQL Via Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, database-cursor, rowtype

Sorry I had to edit this to account for new information.  However what I am trying to do is the same as before. I am trying to basically loop through specific schemas within the same database and access a Table within each schema that every schema has in common (called "Edit").  Then, I want to display the schema name alongside one row of the Edit Table.  However, I keep getting an error saying "syntax error at or near cursor"(this code - CURSOR cur_edtf IS t_query;) I am assuming this means that something is fundamentally wrong with my syntax, but I am very new to Postgres Dynamic SQL and not the best with SQL so I am not totally sure what I am doing wrong... can anyone offer suggestions?

```
      DECLARE
                
          CURSOR cur_project IS SELECT * from data."Project" where "Project"."Complete" = True and "Project"."StatusID"=1;
          proj_entity cur_project%ROWTYPE;
          
          
          t_query text;
    BEGIN  
    
          OPEN cur_project;
          LOOP
                fetch cur_project into proj_entity;
                EXIT WHEN cur_project%NOTFOUND;
                t_query := 'SELECT * from ' || proj_entity."SchemaName" || '."Edit" order by ' || proj_entity."SchemaName" || '."Edit"."Version" desc limit 1;';
                
            CURSOR cur_edtf IS t_query;
              edtf_entity cur_edtf%ROWTYPE;
                
                OPEN cur_edtf;
                LOOP
                    fetch cur_edtf into edtf_entity;
                      EXIT WHEN cur_edtf%NOTFOUND;
                      dbms_output.put_line(proj_entity."SchemaName", edtf_entity);
                END LOOP;
                CLOSE cur_edtf;
                
          END LOOP;
          CLOSE cur_project;
    
    END;
```